# Puppet get content from symlink file

Tags: puppet

Is it possible to get content of symlink on file?

I can create the file with content in case if `fullchain.pem` isn't the symlink.

My configuration for fileserver

```
[shared_files]
    path /etc/puppetlabs/shared_files
    allow *
```

Then I try to pass content to another server

```
file { '/etc/ssl/fullchain.pem':
    ensure => file,
    mode => '0664',
    owner => 'root',
    group => 'root',
    links => follow,
    source_permissions => ignore,
    source => "puppet:///shared_files/fullchain.pem",
  }
```

Thank in advance

Answer (score 2):

I think you're asking about what effect the given `file` resource has if `/etc/puppetlabs/shared_files/fullchain.pem` is a symbolic link on the master.  The basic answer is that Puppet's built-in fileserver follows symbolic links.  This is not clearly documented in the places you might be likely to look, but [the documentation for the fileserver configuration file](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/6.3/config_file_fileserver.html) says so clearly in the following warning:

> **CAUTION**: Always restrict write access to mounted directories. The file server follows any symlinks in a file server mount, including
>   links to files that agent nodes should not access (like SSL keys).
>   When following symlinks, the file server can access any files readable
>   by Puppet Server’s user account.

Note that this has nothing to do with the `links` parameter of the `File` resource. That affects what Puppet does when the specified path on the target node identifies a symbolic link.  Specifically, if `links` is set to `follow`, as in your example, and the local path identifies a symlink, then Puppet will manage the file to which the link points.  Otherwise (if `links` is set to `manage`, the default) the specified path itself is always the one managed.  In that case, if the path initially identified a symlink, then Puppet would replace it with a regular file (supposing the example is otherwise unmodified).